# They Was Gonna - Colloquial Language

Tags: grammar, collocations, colloquial-language

I heard some people saying *"They was..."* instead of *"They were..."*.
Also, it seems that this is usually used with ***gonna*** (e.g. They was gonna use it).

Is this a common colloquial language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These constructions are common in certain dialects of English, although not in standard English. In my experience they are rather more common in the US than in the UK, and are not used in formal writing, except in dialog.

Comment: Very common in many UK local dialects, e.g. London (Cockney, Multicultural London English/MLE etc) also Bristolian, and many other urban dialects,

Comment: @Michael Harvey
 Thanks. It seems my experience is more limited than I had thought.